# Camera images are changing the orientation automatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im developing a photo app.

Here i'm using the images from both photo library and also the images taking through camera and displaying it in a image view.

The images from photo library is coming in correct orientation but camera images are displaying in different orientation.

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
    NSString *imagePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"girl.jpg"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath].CGImage scale:bieberImage.image.scale
                                       orientation:NO]; 

     //   bieberImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);


    CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    crossFade.duration = 3.0;


        crossFade.fromValue = (id)bieberImage.image.CGImage;

        crossFade.toValue = (id)image.CGImage;



        [self.bieberImage.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];

        }
```

Can  anyone tell me how can i correct this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace:

```
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath].CGImage scale:bieberImage.image.scale
                                   orientation:NO];
```

With:

```
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath].CGImage scale:bieberImage.image.scale
                                   orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
```

Edit:
Or try this:

```
 - (UIImage*) rotateImage:(UIImage* )src {

    UIImageOrientation orientation = src.imageOrientation;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
         CGContextRotateCTM (context, [self radians:90]);
     } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
         CGContextRotateCTM (context, [self radians:90]);
     } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
         // NOTHING
     } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
         CGContextRotateCTM (context, [self radians:0]);
     }

      return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 }

 - (CGFloat) radians:(int)degrees {
    return (degrees/180)*(22/7);
  }
```

Comment: That i already tried but still the camera images are not coming in correct orientation.

Comment: is there any other alternative

Comment: See the Edit above - that should rotate your image.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIImage *)update4:(UIImage *)image {

CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
    alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

int width, height;

width = image.size.width;
height = image.size.height;

if(width>320)
{

    width = 320;
    height = height * 320/width;
}

if(height>480)
{
    height = 480;
    width  = width * 480/height;
}

CGContextRef bitmap;

if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp | image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

} else {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, height, width, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, alphaInfo);

}


if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    //NSLog(@"image orientation left");
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, 3.14/180*90);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -height);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    //NSLog(@"image orientation right");
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -3.14/180*90);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -width, 0);

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
    //NSLog(@"image orientation up");   

} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    //NSLog(@"image orientation down"); 
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, width,height);
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -3.14/180*180);

}




CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return result;  
  }


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo   {

UIImage *updateImage =   [self update4:image];
 }
```